# Definite integration evaluation of $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{x}{(a^2\cos^2x+b^2\sin^2x)^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

OK, so the question says evaluate the integral
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{x}{(a^2\cos^2x+b^2\sin^2x)^2}dx$$
What I do is use the property that $\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(b+a-x)dx$ and this gives me ($I$ is the value of the integral)
$$\frac{2I}{\pi}=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{(a^2\cos^2x+b^2\sin^2x)^2}dx$$
What should I do ahead to get the value I need? Any tips? (Thanks in advance)

Comment: Try substitution of $t = \tan(\frac{x}{2})$?

Comment: Don't you think converting to half angles would complicate the question? Did you mean the tan part? I have tried $t=tan(x)$, that solves the integral (indefinite way) but on inserting the limits, I get an indeterminate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to the following method:

\begin{align*}
I
:= \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x}{(a^2 \cos^2 x + b^2 \sin^2 x )^2} \, dx
&= \frac{\pi}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{dx}{(a^2 \cos^2 x + b^2 \sin^2 x )^2} \\
&= \pi \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{dx}{(a^2 \cos^2 x + b^2 \sin^2 x )^2} \\
&= \pi \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1 + \tan^2 x}{(a^2 + b^2 \tan^2 x )^2} \, \sec^2 x \, dx.
\end{align*}

Now we make the substitution $b \tan x \mapsto a \tan x$. Then

\begin{align*}
I
&= \frac{\pi}{(ab)^3} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{b^2 + a^2\tan^2 x}{(1 + \tan^2 x )^2} \, \sec^2 x \, dx \\
&= \frac{\pi}{(ab)^3} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} ( b^2 \cos^2 x + a^2\sin^2 x ) \, dx \\
&= \frac{\pi}{(ab)^3} \cdot \frac{\pi}{4} \left( a^2 + b^2 \right)
 = \frac{\pi^2(a^2 + b^2)}{4(ab)^3}.
\end{align*}

Comment: In the third step(part 1) where you convert the upper limit to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, there, what did you use? Did you use the symmetry of the function $f(x)=a^2cos^2x+b^2sin^2x$, that $f(\frac{\pi}{2}+t)=f(\frac{\pi}{2}-t)$?

Comment: @AshishGaurav: Yes, absolutely right. That was because of the symmetry of the integrand that you pointed out.

Comment: I think you also used that $$\int_0^\pi xf(\sin x)dx=\frac \pi 2 \int_0^\pi f(\sin x)dx$$

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: That's also right, though I skipped the explanation because OP was already well aware of that.

Comment: @SangchulLee Am I missing something here or is $b \tan x \mapsto a \tan x$ a substitution without any change of variable? $b \tan x \mapsto a \tan u$, for example, is what I'm used to seeing.

Comment: @s0ulr3aper07, I would not say this is a good practice, but I overrode the meaning of the variable $x$ to a new one. The main purpose of doing so, even at the risk of introducing possible source of ambiguity, is not to introduce many variable names, especially when they are only dummy variables.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\because I&=\int_0^\pi \frac{x}{\left(a^2 \cos ^2 x+b^2 \sin ^2 x\right)^2} \\& \stackrel{x\mapsto\pi-x}{=} \int_0^\pi \frac{\pi-x}{\left(a^2 \cos ^2 x+b^2 \sin ^2 x\right)^2} d x \\
&=\pi \int_0^\pi \frac{d x}{\left(a^2 \cos ^2 x+b^2 \sin ^2 x\right)^2}-I \\
\therefore I&=\frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^\pi \frac{d x}{\left(a^2 \cos ^2 x+b^2 \sin ^2 x\right)^2} \\
&=\pi \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d x}{\left(a^2 \cos ^2 x+b^2 \sin ^2 x\right)^2}
\end{aligned}
$$

By my [post](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-value-of-int-frac-%CF%80-2-0-frac-1-a-2-cos-2-x-b-2-sin-2-x-2-dx/answer/Lai-Johnny?ch=17&oid=349365811&share=74f378b8&srid=CCOmo&target_type=answer), $$
\boxed{I =\pi\left[\frac{\pi\left(a^2+b^2\right)}{4 a^3 b^3}\right]=\frac{\pi^2\left(a^2+b^2\right)}{4 a^3 b^3}}
$$